# Python How to convert collections.OrderedDict to dataFrame

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, ordereddict

I have the following task:
1) I have an excel file with a few spreadsheets. From these spreadsheets I need information from columns "A:CU", rows 41 - 51
2) Then I need to collect information from from columns "A:CU", rows 41 - 51 from all spreadsheets (they have the same structure) and to create a database.
3) There should be a column that indicates from which spreadsheet data was collected

I did following:

```
import pandas as pd
file='January2020.xlsx'
#getting info from spreadsheets C(1), C(2) and so on
days = range(1,32)
sheets = []
for day in days:
    sheets.append('C(' + str(day)+')')
#importing data
all_sales=pd.read_excel(file,header=None,skiprows=41, usecols="A:CU", sheet_name=sheets,
                skipfooter=10)
```

Now I have collections.OrderedDict and struggle to put it into dataFrame.

[image]

What I need to have is a dataframe like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and it worked:

```
file='January2020.xlsx'
days = range(1,32)
all_sales=pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()
all_df = []
for day in days:
    sheet_name = "C("+str(day)+")"
    all_sales=pd.read_excel(file,header=None,skiprows=41,usecols="A:CU", sheet_name=sheet_name,
                skipfooter=10)
    all_sales["Date"] = sheet_name
    all_df.append(all_sales)
df_final = pd.concat(all_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat(all_sales, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: no, It doesn'r work. I got a column with C(1), C(2)...without any other data

Comment: I also tried this  code :  ```xls=pd.ExcelFile(file); df=xls.parse("C(1)", header=None, skiprows=40, usecols="A:CU", skipfooter=10); 
df.insert(0,"Date","C(1)")```  It works perfectly with 1 spreadsheet. Then I try to go through spreadsheets C(1) - C(31) with this code : 
```days = range(1,32)
sheets = []
for day in days:
    sheets.append('C(' + str(day)+')')
    xls=pd.ExcelFile(file)
    df=xls.parse(sheets, header=None, skiprows=40, usecols="A:CU", skipfooter=10)
    df.insert(0,"Date",sheets) ``` but again end up with 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'insert'